# How to Adjust time on php script?

Tags: php, html

My php script shows time by this

```
echo "<a href=\"time.php?hits=$hits\">".date("h:i:s A")."</a></div>";
```

Problem is server time is different from us. Server gives 11 hours back time from my current zone. If my real time is 15 Aug 10 PM server is showing 15 Aug 11 AM!

How can I fast my clock 11 hours on above script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GOOGLE "PHP timezones change"

```
putenv("TZ=Europe/London");
```

or if that produces an error:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

if you can gain access to your php.ini

```
date.timezone = "Europe/London"
```

in the ini

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
```

**OR**

for your solution here it is `date('h:i:s A', time()+36000)`  just adjust the seconds my friend

Answer (score 1):

[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). This changes the time zone for all date-function calls. (See Manual.)

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
you can get list of time zones here http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php
```